# how to add user to sharepoint list item user field using REST api in sp2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a basic sharepoint list with people field in it, now I am trying to use rest api to add new list item and trying to set person field to my alias but it is not working and throwing me below error. looks like it is problem with how my user data is passed but I could not able to find any help online.

can you guys help with the correct way to make this call, any help is greatly appreciated.

my Code----------

```
function runAjax(){   var d  = JSON.stringify({"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.RepositoryItem"},"Owners":"-1;#v-mynme@microsoft.com"});
jQuery.ajax({ 
    url: "https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/docstore/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Repository')/items(1580) ",
    type: "POST", 
    headers: { 
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose", 
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(), 
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE", 
        "If-Match": "*" 
    }, 
    data:d, 
    success: function (_a) { 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(_a)); 
    }, 
    error: function (_e) { 
        console.error(JSON.stringify(_e)); 
    } 
});}runAjax();
```

error I am getting is

```
Updation fail
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"A 'PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of a navigation property; however, a 'StartArray' node, a 'StartObject' node, or a 'PrimitiveValue' node with null value was expected.\"}}}","status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-operation-to-list-using-SharePoint-Rest-API

Answer (score 13):

### How to set User field value using SharePoint REST API

Assume the following function is used for creating a list item using SharePoint REST:

```
function createListItem(webUrl,listName,itemProperties) 
{    
    return $.ajax({       
       url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",   
       type: "POST",   
       processData: false,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
       headers: {   
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
          "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
       }  
    });
}
```

The format for user field value:

- single-valued user field: `'<user field name>' : <user id>`
- multi-valued user field: `'<user field name>' : { 'results': [<array of user ids>] }`

**Multiple user field value**

The example demonstrates how to create a task item and specify **multi**-valued `AssignedTo` field:

```
//Create a Task item
var taskProperties = {
    '__metadata' : { 'type': 'SP.Data.TasksListItem' },
    'Title': 'Order approval',
    'AssignedToId' : { 'results': [10] }
};
createListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Tasks',taskProperties)
.done(function(data)
{
   console.log('Task has been created successfully');
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

**Single user field value**

The example demonstrates how to create a task item and specify a **single**-valued `AssignedTo` field:

```
//Create a Task item
var taskProperties = {
    '__metadata' : { 'type': 'SP.Data.TasksListItem' },
    'Title': 'Order approval',
    'AssignedToId' : 10
};
createListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Tasks',taskProperties)
.done(function(data)
{
   console.log('Task has been created successfully');
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: everything is fine with your answer, but it is important to mention that as developer you should add "Id" at the end of feild name. For instance "Owners" filed should become "OwnersId", and in you example "AssignedTo" became "AssignedToId". It is not obvious from scratch, believe me :)

Comment: What is the value I should use if I want to clear the field?

Answer (score 2):

The error message you are receiving can be confusing. In this case, though the Person/Group field is named (display or internal name of the SharePoint list field) "Owners", when using REST API to update this field, it may be something else.

```
{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.RepositoryItem"},"Owners":"-1;#vmynme@microsoft.com"}
```

To find out the exact field definition, try the following URL using GET method and investigate the XML value returned.

```
https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/docstore/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Repository')/items(1580)
```

The XML may look something like the following

```
<m:properties> 
...
<d:DateModified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2014-01-07T00:00:00Z</d:DateModified><d:OwnersById m:null="true" />
...
</m:properties>
```

Most likely you will notice that the field "Owners" is named something else, such as "OwnersId". You will need to reconstruct your ajax post data to use the exact field name and specify the user's **Id** property instead of user's **LoginName** property as the posted value.

Answer (score 2):

The right way should be as shown below: (I am sure it will save someone sometime)

```
 var requestApprover = {
                        '__metadata' : { 'type': 'Collection(Edm.Int32)' },
                        'results': [10,20,30]
                    };
```

Remember the field name should contain Id at the end and the type should be the field type that you are updating where for people or groups (multiple) is Collection(Edm.Int32).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the Claims Encoding of the username. That is the way I update such types of fields.
Example:
"i:0#.w|contoso\chris"

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the POST call using this syntax for your User Field:

If field has name "Owners", you need to send `"OwnersId": 1` inside your REST call body (Append ID to your column name and pass the value of UserID).

If you need to check what is the exact name of the User column, start your F12 Dev Tools in the browser, Start Network Capture and then type in your URL in the browser.

```
"https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/docstore/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Repository')/items(1580) "
```

In the response body, you will see exact names of all columns (as used in REST)