# Adding a sharepoint list item, which has column of type "Person or Group" in it

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I am trying to add an item to a list. The list has 2 columns in it: `Title` and `recipientId` (it is of type `Person` or `Group`). Now I am using

```
https:<site url>/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('list name'>)/items
```

to create the list. Unfortunately I am unable to figure out what value I should be giving to `recipientId` (some blogs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500077/how-to-add-user-to-sharepoint-list-item-user-field-using-rest-api-in-sp2013?rq=1) mentioned we have to provide the user id. If that is right, how do I get that id or what exactly I should give there for the user to get added there?) This is the json I am using in post man to create the item:

```json
{ "__metadata": 
   {
       "type": "SP.Data.List3ListItem"
   },
   "Title": "Teams incorporate feedback"
}
```

[image]

Comment: In what language? Using what library? A GET on `https:/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('list name'>)/items ` doesn't create anything. SharePoint's APIs are documented, have you tried reading the docs? Using the client libraries?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint#create-update-and-delete-list-items) shows how to create, edit or delete list items

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am not using any Language here I just trying it from postman and I am doing a POST on  https:<site url>/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('list name'>)/items

Comment: So you *are* using the REST API. You don't know which version though. Read the docs please, don't just try things at random. You'll find the docs for the various REST API versions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/sharepoint-rest-graph). The SharePoint version matters, as SharePoint online has moved to the Graph API

Comment: yes I did read the document and it is SharePoint 13 and I am able to add the items If you see the attachment I have shared in my question but, I am not able to add value to the field "recipientId" which of type people or group.

Comment: Read the docs. Don't try random snippets from questions that may or may not have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: thanks @PanagiotisKanavos I got it!

Answer (score 1):

If your column allow mutiple value:

```
{
       "__metadata":{
          "type":"SP.Data.TestListItem"//change this value to yours 
       },
       "Title":"Test",
       "supervisorId":{
          "results":[25,26]//user ids
       }
    }
```

If your column only allow single value:

```
{
   "__metadata":{
      "type":"SP.Data.TestListItem"
   },
   "Title":"Test",
   "supervisorId":5
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this might save someone's time,

so to add a value for a column of type "person or Group"(recipientId in my case). Firstly, we need to have the site users id that you can get from REST API **https://<site_url>/sites/<site_name>/_api/web/siteusers**. Once you have the ID, you can add it as value for  "UsernameId" key value

```
    { "__metadata": 
{
"type": "SP.Data.List3ListItem"
    
},
"Title": "Varun",
"UsernameId":13

 }
```

this will add the corresponding user name to the column of type "person or Group"(recipientId in my case).[image]